# MappingException: target entity not found

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm mapping an n:m relationship and I do it as follow:

**Device\DeviceBundle\Entity\DriverHasDevice.php**

```
namespace Device\DeviceBundle\Entity;

use Driver\DriverBundle\Entity\Driver;
use Device\DeviceBundle\Entity\Device;

class DriverHasDevice
{

    protected $driver;
    protected $device;

    public function setDriver(Driver $driver)
    {
        $this->driver = $driver;
    }

    public function getDriver()
    {
        return $this->driver;
    }

    public function setDevice(Device $device)
    {
        $this->device = $device;
    }

    public function getDevice()
    {
        return $this->device;
    }

}
```

**Device\DeviceBundle\Resources\config\doctrine\DriverHasDevice.orm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                        http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">

    <entity name="Device\DeviceBundle\Entity\DriverHasDevice" table="driver_has_device">
        <id name="driver" association-key="true" />
        <id name="device" association-key="true" />
        
        <many-to-one field="driver" target-entity="Driver\DriverBundle\Entity\Driver" />
        <many-to-one field="device" target-entity="Device\DeviceBundle\Entity\Device" />
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

**Driver\DriverBundle\Entity\Driver.php**

```
namespace TaxiBooking\Driver\DriverBundle\Entity;


class Driver
{
    protected $id;

    protected $name;

    protected $status;


    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    public function setStatus($status)
    {
        $this->status = $status;
    }
}
```

**Driver\DriverBundle\Resources\config\doctrine\Driver.orm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
                  xmlns:gedmo="http://gediminasm.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-extensions-mapping"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
    <entity name="Driver\DriverBundle\Entity\Driver" table="driver"
            repository-class="Driver\DriverBundle\Entity\Driver">
        <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
            <generator strategy="AUTO"/>
        </id>
        <field name="name" type="string" column="name" length="50" precision="0" scale="0" nullable="true"/>
        <field name="status" type="integer" column="status" length="1" precision="0" scale="0" nullable="true"/>
        <gedmo:soft-deleteable field-name="deletedAt" time-aware="false"/>
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

Now I'm trying to validate the schema running the command `Symfony > doctrine:schema:validate` from Symfony2 shell and I get this error:

> [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]   The target-entity
> Driver\DriverBundle\Entity\Driver cannot be found in
> 'Device\DeviceBundle\Entity\DriverHasDevice#driver'.

Where is the problem in my mapping? I can't see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your looking for the wrong namespace.
Your Driver Entity has **TaxiBooking\Driver\DriverBundle\Entity** namespace.

Change the Driver namespace or change the references to it.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking on the right namespace I just forgot totally to upload new bundles to development so was my bad